# Image resizing on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, constraints

I am having trouble with the last step of my application.
I will show you guys some images to explain what is happening:

This is how it looks in the storyboard:

[image]

Here is the constraints that i am using:

[image]

And here is how it looks in a real iphone 6 plus device:

[image]

It does not look like this on the simulator. And on iPhone 5/6 it looks normal. So why is it being stretched on the 6 plus. As you can see from the constraints i put the width and height to be constant?

Thank you

Comment: Can u add the scrrenshot of the simulator as well ?

Comment: Is the align-y constraint -175.0 correct ? Why do you need that much offset ?

Comment: Okay thats weird, i just noticed that it gets stretched in the simulator also. Well now. What do you suggest that i change to make this work @TejaNandamuri

Comment: looks like the height constraint 70 is too much. You can make it 50.

Comment: Thats what i am using in the storyboard. Should it not be the same? @TejaNandamuri

Comment: The thing is, what you are seeing in storyboard is sized to 600x600. Hence it doesnt look stretched. But for iphone device, 70 height is what it looks like in the screenshot hence it gives you the stretched result.

Comment: No thats no true. In my text i wrote that the image looks normal in iphone 5/6 which has smaller screens. Get it ? @TejaNandamuri